# MongoDB,the DB connection script does not work

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb

DB connection does not work. Could anyone tell me why?

**HTML page:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Connection.js"></script>
</head>
<body>   
</body>
</html>
```

**Js page:**

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/DBName";
        
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    if (err) throw err;
    alert("OK");
    db.close();
});
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Connection script seems fine.Were you able to set path for mongoDb? Let us know more about your issue.

Comment: If I run the .js file with the terminal it runs but if I connect the .js file to the html it doesn't work (it doesn't print anything)